# Are passive abilities automatically enabled?

Tags: resident-evil-orc

After purchasing my first perk, [body armor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrYBe.png), the game doesn't show the ability in character stats:

[image]

Are passive perks always enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the wikia](http://residentevil.wikia.com/wiki/Resident_Evil:_Operation_Raccoon_City/gameplay), it looks like, **yes**, passive perks are always enabled.

> Passive abilities are *always* active in the game, but active abilities need to be manually activated.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>